# HTML5 File API Upload Multiple Images with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fileapi

I am trying to upload multiple images with [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/). I want to show picture thumbnails and their names as title tag. The problem is I am not getting correct picture name as title tag.  All pictures are showing same name.
Here is my Original code...

**jQuery, CSS and HTML**

```js
var output = document.getElementById("result");

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //Check File API support
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        $('#files').on("change", function (event)
        {
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

            var iCount = files.length;

            for (var i = 0, f; i < iCount; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
                //Only pics
                if (file.type.match('image.*'))
                {
                    var picReader = new FileReader();

                    picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event)
                    {
                        var picFile = event.target;
                    
                        var div = document.createElement("div");

                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + file['name'] + "'/>";
                        output.insertBefore(div, null);
                        
                    });

                    //Read the image
                    $('#clear, #result').show();
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You can only upload image file.");
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }


    $("#upload").on('submit',(function()
    {
        var data = new FormData(this);

        var iUploaded = 0;
        
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            var iCount = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < iCount ; i++)
            {
                data.append("Index", i);
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        var sRes = response.split("|-|");
                        
                        if(sRes['0'] == 'success')
                        {
                            iUploaded = iUploaded + 1;
                            $("#message").html(iUploaded + " of " + sRes['1'] + " Pictures Uploaded")
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }));
    

    $("#files").change(function()
    {
        $("#submit").trigger("click");
    });


    $('#clear').on("click", function ()
    {
        $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#files').val("");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

        header h1{
            font-size:12pt;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1BA1E2;
            padding: 20px;

        }
        article
        {
            width: 80%;
            margin:auto;
            margin-top:10px;
        }


        .thumbnail{

            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        #clear{
            display:none;
        }
        #result {
            border: 4px dotted #cccccc;
            display: none;
            float: left;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        #result > div {
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
    <form id="upload" onsubmit="return false">
        <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label><br /><br />
        <input id="files" name="files[]" type="file" multiple/><br /><br />
        <input type="Submit" value="submit" id="submit"></input>
        <button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button><br /><br />
    </form>

    <div id="message"></div>
    <output id="result" />
</article>
```

I tried to figure it out and come to know that the value of `var i`  changes automatically inside the

`addEventListener("load", function (event){
    // value of “var i” is not the same here as the value coming from outside this function.
});`

I have no idea why value is changing inside the “load” function.

I Googled to see how others are doing same and ended up with this working example on SitePoint http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/
In this example I see these 2 major differences which I do not understand (my little knowledge in programming).

**1. Syntax of for loop he is using in example**

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
```

See he is assigning value to `var f` instead of applying stop condition.
Now my question is how the loop is working without stop condition is specified?

**2. Separate function for reading files**

He has made a separate function `ParseFile();` to read files.
When I tried to read files without a separate function for file reading it is not working (as shown in my original code). But when I put that code in a separate function `showThumbnail()` for reading files and call that function inside loop it is working as it should be (as showing in below snippet). Why is this so?

Anyone here explain these two things to me.
Thanks in advance.

I followed the example and rearranged my code which is working as it should be.  (Code is in below snippet.)

```js
var output = document.getElementById("result");

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //Check File API support
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        $('#files').on("change", function (event)
        {
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

            var iCount = files.length;

            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
            {
                showThumbnail(f);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }


    $("#upload").on('submit',(function()
    {
        var data = new FormData(this);

        var iUploaded = 0;
        
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            var iCount = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < iCount ; i++)
            {
                data.append("Index", i);
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        var sRes = response.split("|-|");
                        
                        if(sRes['0'] == 'success')
                        {
                            iUploaded = iUploaded + 1;
                            $("#message").html(iUploaded + " of " + sRes['1'] + " Pictures Uploaded")
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }));
    

    $("#files").change(function()
    {
        $("#submit").trigger("click");
    });


    $('#clear').on("click", function ()
    {
        $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#files').val("");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});


function showThumbnail(file)
{
    //Only pics
    if (file.type.match('image.*'))
    {
        var picReader = new FileReader();

        picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event)
        {
            var picFile = event.target;
        
            var div = document.createElement("div");

            div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
            "title='" + file['name'] + "'/>";
            output.insertBefore(div, null);
            
        });

        //Read the image
        $('#clear, #result').show();
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You can only upload image file.");
        $(this).val("");
    }

}
```

```css
 body{
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

        header h1{
            font-size:12pt;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1BA1E2;
            padding: 20px;

        }
        article
        {
            width: 80%;
            margin:auto;
            margin-top:10px;
        }


        .thumbnail{

            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        #clear{
            display:none;
        }
        #result {
            border: 4px dotted #cccccc;
            display: none;
            float: left;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        #result > div {
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
    <form id="upload" onsubmit="return false">
        <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label><br /><br />
        <input id="files" name="files[]" type="file" multiple/><br /><br />
        <input type="Submit" value="submit" id="submit"></input>
        <button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button><br /><br />
    </form>

    <div id="message"></div>
    <output id="result" />
</article>
```

Comment: put your question first as it is not clear what you want amongst all that guff

Comment: @AstraBear : Sorry I am not good at English... and this is my question on stackoverflow. Let me edit it and I will try to reformat my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Astra Bear :  Dear I have improved the formatting to make it as understandable as I can. Please have a look and tell me if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Haven't seen the edits to question before posting + misread it**
So for your questions :

- **1**  This for loop is waiting for file[i] to be undefined. :
  `for( var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++)`.
  If `files[x]`is undefined, then the loop stops (even if files[x+1] is defined)
- **2**  It is because in your first snippet, your `file` variable is in the global scope and gets replaced during the iteration. In the second, however, it is linked to the `showThumbnail` function scope, and then passed in the EventListener.
  To avoid calling an external function, you will need to call a `file` binded function :

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) :  `reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);`

So for you,

```
picReader.addEventListener("load", (function(aImg) { return function (event)
                    {
                        var picFile = event.target;
                        console.log(picFile);
                        var div = document.createElement("div");

                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + aImg['name'] + "'/>";
                        output.insertBefore(div, null);

                    }; })(file));
```

**Example below :**

```js
var output = document.getElementById("result");

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //Check File API support
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        $('#files').on("change", function (event)
        {
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object

            var iCount = files.length;

            for (var i = 0, f; i < iCount; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
                //Only pics
                if (file.type.match('image.*'))
                {
                    var picReader = new FileReader();

                    picReader.addEventListener("load", (function(aImg) { return function (event)
                    {
                        var picFile = event.target;
                        console.log(picFile);
                        var div = document.createElement("div");

                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + aImg['name'] + "'/>";
                        output.insertBefore(div, null);
                        
                    }; })(file));

                    //Read the image
                    $('#clear, #result').show();
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You can only upload image file.");
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }


    $("#upload").on('submit',(function()
    {
        var data = new FormData(this);

        var iUploaded = 0;
        
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            var iCount = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < iCount ; i++)
            {
                data.append("Index", i);
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        var sRes = response.split("|-|");
                        
                        if(sRes['0'] == 'success')
                        {
                            iUploaded = iUploaded + 1;
                            $("#message").html(iUploaded + " of " + sRes['1'] + " Pictures Uploaded")
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }));
    

    $("#files").change(function()
    {
        $("#submit").trigger("click");
    });


    $('#clear').on("click", function ()
    {
        $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#files').val("");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

        header h1{
            font-size:12pt;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1BA1E2;
            padding: 20px;

        }
        article
        {
            width: 80%;
            margin:auto;
            margin-top:10px;
        }


        .thumbnail{

            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        #clear{
            display:none;
        }
        #result {
            border: 4px dotted #cccccc;
            display: none;
            float: left;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        #result > div {
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
    <form id="upload" onsubmit="return false">
        <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label><br /><br />
        <input id="files" name="files[]" type="file" multiple/><br /><br />
        <input type="Submit" value="submit" id="submit"></input>
        <button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button><br /><br />
    </form>

    <div id="message"></div>
    <output id="result" />
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1:**

The for loop increments `i` with 1 on every iteration. When `i` is not an index of `files` the returned value will be undefined, which breaks the loop.

**Answer to question 2:**

I created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pLru1Ln/)** which shows how to put the code of `showThumbnail` in the for loop. It aslo explains the question.

The reason is behind the `addEventListener` function, which will run asynchronously with the for loop after `load` is triggered and has different scope. The function outside the loop is however permanent and the listener can use variables declared in that scope (the argument `file`).

What you can do however is to bind the listener function to the file object. The scope (`this`) of the function will be the file. See the fiddle for this to work.